# how much vertices in SceneKit can apple devices handle

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, scenekit

I am designing a 3D game for ipad and iphone using SceneKit. I noticed that the ipad 3 cant handle the game, although I only use less than 3k vertices and 2 lights. Pretty strange. Could someone give approximate numbers of how how much vertices counted by sceneKit statistics can various Aplle devices handle?

EDIT: I'm down on 500 vertices. It STILL cant handle it :O

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fillrate is far and away the primary limiting factor on anything less than an iPad Air 2 and the new iPhone 6S/6S Plus. This is particular true on the iPad 3rd Gen, iPhone 4/4S and even on the iPhone 5 and iPad 4.

The iPad 4th Gen is actually a bit of a geometry specialist, it's GPU able to handle more vertices than the A7 iPad Air that followed it.

It's easily possible to throw 150k vertices around at 60fps on an iPad 3rd Gen... but as soon as you put some challenging blending in your rendering  you'll slow to a crawl.

You are probably hitting a fillrate limit of some sort. How big is your geometry, the textures on it, and how much blending are you doing?

Comment: hey, thanks for stopping by. I am a little noobish as far as 3D games goes. What is fillrate and what exactly do you mean by blending?

Comment: Blending is any calculation wherein a texture, drawing, shape or material is required to "see through" to something beneath it, and calculate the resulting effect of its transparency upon those layers underneath it. This can come about because the "material" is partly transparent and/or because you're using Multiply/Additive/Screen or some other blend calculation that computes a change in the pixels underneath. If you don't know about this you're probably not using it.

Comment: oh i see. I added a screen shot of my material properties. I changed the diffuse in code, but everything else is the same. What about fill rate?

Comment: Fillrate is the amount of drawing the GPU is doing, you can sort of think of this as 2D pixels in 3D space, but it's not really like that... but that's close enough to understand the saturation point. If you make big objects that obscure each other, and go so large they're way off the screen, there's a chance all of that is being drawn by the GPU. This is probably your problem, that there's so much drawing of textures going on that you're saturating the limits of the filtrate of the measly little GPU on the iPad 3rd Gen.

Comment: So the likely more important thing is "how big are your objects?"

Comment: If you make some planes, and throw some big textures on them, and then move them around, you'll find that just 3 or 4 BIG planes with big textures on them can humble the iPad 3.

Comment: So it's possible to bring it to a crawl with less than 30 vertices, thanks to the filtrate problems of drawing all those "pixels" to a buffer, and then to the screen.

Comment: A little down this page is a graph that shows the massive jump in iPad Air 2 filtrate performance compared to some other Apple devices: http://www.anandtech.com/show/8716/apple-a8xs-gpu-gxa6850-even-better-than-i-thought

Comment: I use floor geometry, custom object made in Blender and 2 lights. The floor is infinite, but only a part of it gets captured by camera. It seems like it is something that you have talked about. Custom object has 7 materials. Viewing from user perspective it is only about 1 cm or 2 big but I cannot really tell you its size because it is made in blender. material textures are aproximately 450pixels wide and tall and I use mipmap filter. Thats about it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91031/discussion-between-confused-and-krompir2).